# divisor class group with modulus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, class-field-theory

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over a field $k$ and $S \subset C$ a finite number of points. A modulus is simply a divisor supported on $S$. What is the divisor class group with modulus?

I have seen the definition
$$
\mathrm{coker}(k(C)^\times \to \bigoplus_{x \in X-S} \mathbb{Z} \oplus \bigoplus_{x \in S} k(C)^\times / 1+\mathfrak{m}_x)
$$ but it does not speak to me... What is the meaning of this group, the intuition behind the definition? How is it related to class field theory?

Comment: See Serre *Algebraic Groups and Class Fields*.

Comment: Could you give me a more precise reference, e.g. chapter, section?

Comment: I would say the whole book is about the subject; in particular chapters 5 and 6.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at Serre's book. But maybe you can give me some guidelines?

Comment: Serre does it much better than I could. And I don't know what you are interested in. You better look at the book.